Couldn't a perfectly good God have created beings who are both free and without an inclination to do evil?
If God is omnipotent, why couldn’t He create beings for whom there is likewise no possible world where they choose to sin? It seems that if God creates beings like Himself, those beings would also never sin, making the idea of punishing sin irrelevant. Has any philosopher of religion ever argued to reconcile the following propositions:

(1) God is perfectly good,
(2) God is omnipotent, and
(3) God is unable to create beings who are perfectly good from the get-go (who cannot sin)?

Is there a metaphysical law that prevents God from creating beings like Himself who cannot sin?

The following are alternative ways of phrasing my question, considering nuances brought up by the answers that have been posted so far:

Is it metaphysically impossible for God to create beings like Himself who cannot sin, and if so, why?
Is it logically impossible for God to create beings like Himself who cannot sin, and if so, where is the logical contradiction?
If God has no inclination to sin (without that making God an automaton, a puppet, or a pet), why didn't He create beings with no inclination to sin (without that likewise making those beings automatons, puppets, or pets)?


If God has no inclination to sin, does that mean that God lacks freedom? Does God have free will? If God has both free will and no inclination to sin, there is no contradiction between the two propositions, right? If so, what would prevent God from creating beings that, likewise, have both freedom and no inclination to sin? On the other hand, if the two propositions are contradictory for created beings, why wouldn't they also be contradictory for God?

The question has been closed as a duplicate of:

How does Plantinga's free will defense of God's benevolence work?
Isn't the existence of Hell inherently evil, and isn't God therefore evil in allowing Hell to exist?

Regarding the first question, I disagree. My question is not married to Plantinga's free will defense, as if Plantinga represented the only possible response that humanity has ever produced and will ever produce.
Regarding the second question, I disagree. My question is not about whether God is evil, but about whether there are underlying metaphysical or logical limitations that prevent God from creating beings that are not susceptible to sinning while still remaining free. Please, I invite those who think I'm suggesting that God is evil to spell out exactly how one question is logically equivalent to the other. I'm failing to see how that's the case.
User @tkruse also claimed in the comments that my question is a duplicate of How can a Wholly Good God Deliberately Create Evil? on the Christianity site. Again, I completely disagree. That question doesn't address at all the nuance my question is focused on, namely, whether there are metaphysical limitations that prevent God from creating beings who are both free and without an inclination to sin.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

While I agree the two listed questions are off from the topic of this one, I did a further search myself, and found what looks to be a virtually identical question here:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/99881/how-do-adherents-to-plantingas-free-will-defense-against-the-problem-of-evil  I note that my accepted answer posted there is a somewhat elaborated version of the accepted answer posted here, reinforcing that the two questions are equivalent.  Removing my reopen vote.

Your argument is if God could create the inclination to sin, how could God judge its creation if some of that creation were subject to that inclination. You must have no self control? I suspect God and it's creation are free to choose, and its inclination to sin is a temptation, and that temptation that God never succomed to is why God is able to judge that creation.

@8Mad0Manc8 "Your argument is if God could create the inclination to sin, how could God judge its creation if some of that creation were subject to that inclination." I never made that argument in the entire OP.

@Dcleve Wow, that's indeed a very similar question, great find.

It's sometimes difficult when we know a question has a duplicate, but we cannot quickly find the exact duplicate, only the 10 second best similar questions.

@user80226 Just exactly what is your point? God Is subject to the same inclinations as we are. If God in its omnipotence created a being that did not have the same inclinations as it did then it cannot justifiably judge that creation. If it created by its onipotebce humans that were not susceptible to the inclination to sin, then it would be a false world? Please educate me..

short answer
No.
An omni-God can create any kind of world, and beings in it.  And beings that have free will, but loving rather than cruel inclinations -- are not just possible, but are what a loving God would have done.
Longer Answer
There are a lot of rationalizations that are thrown around related to free will and the problem of evil.  There are several simple answers that scuttle all of them, including the point above about inclinations.  Additionally here are two more critical rebuttals:

The "free will" answer holds that free will is such a great good that it more than counterbalances all the evil in the world.  However, humans have fairly little free will.  With stronger wills to avoid temptation or influence, more knowledge, better judgement, and more autonomy for each of us, we would be MORE free.  As freedom is an absolute good, more than all evil combined, any Omni-God would have made us maximally free, to achieve even greater good.  Of course, when presented this argument , the apologists immediately point out the benefits of less freedom -- refuting the core premise that freedom is so important, it counteracts all extreme evils!
Very little of the evil in the world is due to humans, so free will is actually irrelevant to most of the problem of evil.  The greater issue is that the world has limited resources, and life multiplies beyond profusion -- guaranteeing mass violence and starvation.  If our world is designed, then this great evil is embedded in basic design choices.

This takes us back to the problem of evil
This is all a subset of the Problem of Evil debate.  The Free Will defense is a common tactic by theists, and your question is one method of critiquing the Free Will defense.

@andros -- we humans have predispositions -- natures.  It is plausible  that having a nature leaves us less free than if we didn't; but having a DIFFERNET nature should not change our degree of freedom.  Being more loving, and less cruel or selfish, would not change our degree of freedom.

@andrós yes, an addict is less free than a person not addicted.  If freedom is an absolute value, more so than any evil, then an Omni-God would never have made us prone to addiction.

@andrós If this world is in the perfect balance, then Fritzl is an example of perfection in application.  It is manifestly evident, by anyone with a moral sense, that our universe is FAR from a perfect place.  Neither free will, nor our predilections, nor the basic issue of struggle for limited resources, is even remotely close to moral optimization.  The best we can say is that this world has enough good in it that it was not designed by an EVIL God either.

The typical theological answer to this question is that the only way to make people incapable of sin is to make them incapable of free choice, and if people are incapable of free choice they are incapable of being sinful or virtuous, of being evil or good. Such people would be animals, or puppets, or automatons, only capable of doing what their nature dictates.
If a God wants a world in which people can be good, it has to allow that people can be bad, and that people who are bad can seek and find redemption. This isn't a metaphysical law as much as a logical condition necessary to achieve the goal.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Most religions do not posit a metaphysical law that would prevent the "perfect" sinless creation you ask about. This is why the existence of sin or evil is considered a "problem" in philosophy.

Then why did God choose not to create beings who are perfectly good from the get go? What have folks who study philosophy of religion said about this conundrum?

First, I don't see any logical or metaphysical impossibility in God creating creatures capable only of good.  Even if He created them with the natural ability to choose evil, it seems to me that He could have simply chosen not to create anyone whom He knew would ultimately reject Him.  Some (like open theologians) would try to answer by saying that even God doesn't know the free choices people will make ahead of time; and others might suggest it's "infeasible" (vs. metaphysically impossible) for God to create free creatures who always, every time, choose right.  But as far as I'm concerned, I don't see any logical or metaphysical impossibility with making creatures incapable of choosing evil.  (I do, however, think there is a logical problem with a good God creating within people an inclination toward evil, and I would reject that idea.)
And so I think this hinges on the goodness of God part of your question.  Yet I would say it's impossible to philosophically falsify this concept.  We may wonder, Why would God allow the door of evil to be cracked open by creating this kind of creaturely freedom, rather than slamming the door, locking it, and welding it shut?  But to answer would require us to run "simulations" of the various ways God could have created the world, with all of their respective complexities, and to accurately judge which is best on the whole, and in the end.  But my brain tends to overheat simply trying to understand some technical books--let alone trying to comprehend the full spectrum of complexity in this world; and further, let alone trying to comprehend the complexity of all other possible worlds!  As long as it is conceivable, in theory, for God to bring greater good from creating this kind of free will, then it is a philosophically justified concept.  I would argue that this is indeed the case.  I heard a Christian philosopher, Phil Fernandez, say something like: This isn't the best possible world, but it's the best possible way to the best possible world.
I think it partly boils down to our limited perspective and intelligence as finite humans.  It might be similar to a toddler listening to his father talk of all the politics at work, and saying, "Daddy, if you just gave them candy, they would all be your friends!"  The father might smile and think how much his son has to learn about the complexities of the the grown-up world.  I suspect God must think that way about us sometimes.  :)  Paul actually discusses many of these same topics in your question in the book of Romans; and after giving a (glimpse) of ways God can bring a greater good out of it all, he sums up with the same basic point about how these kinds of things surpass our understanding in many ways (Romans 11:33-34):

O the depth of the riches both of the wisdom and knowledge of God! how unsearchable are his judgments, and his ways past finding out!  For who hath known the mind of the Lord? or who hath been his counsellor?


"As long as it is conceivable, in theory, for God to bring greater good from creating this kind of free will, then it is a philosophically justified concept." No, it's only in apologetics that such weak reasoning is considered valid. Please limit yourself to good reasoning here.

@JonathanZ But the counterclaim is absolute--the claim that there is no possible way for God to bring greater good out of it all.  Without that claim, there is no other logical or philosophical objection to the concept of a good God creating free will, even given all it entails.  And such an absolute negative is quite weak in my view, requiring only a theoretical counterexample to topple.

Who's making that counter claim? Not me. You're the one who seems to have made the jump from "can't be disproved" to "philosophically justified concept". It's as valid as Russel's teapot. If that's the only claim you want to make, then please be clear about that.

@JonathanZ The original question title, at the time of this answer, was, "Can the concept of a perfectly good God creating beings vulnerable to sin be philosophically justified?"  I would respond yes, because there is no logical or philosophical problem, only a practical objection which cannot possibly be proved, and can be easily disproved in theory.  However, if the question had been, "Can the concept of a perfectly good God creating an inclination toward evil be philosophically justified?"  I would have responded with, "No"

Religion and philosophy are two different things. Philosophy is not generally applicable to religious arguments. Religion is about believing things without requiring a particularly objective/logical foundation. You would have to ask this a priest in your religion; or a historian who has studied the texts of your religion. Any religious person would scoff at an argument brought forth from a philosophical standpoint (unless it agrees with their belief system).
From experience: this kind of question, in many variations, comes up since the beginning of time (or at least since the beginning of religions). The same set of questions is then used by atheists to point out the absurdity of a God figure; and by religious people to point out the wisdom of their system, in some way. If any of these arguments had a solution that satisfied philosophers as well as religious people, we would all either believe or not believe.


Is there a metaphysical law that prevents God from creating beings
like Himself who cannot sin?

No there is no such law

what would prevent God from creating beings that, likewise, have both freedom and no inclination to sin?

Nothing. Your question seems like we are only God's creation. But there are "lower beings" like ants and from biblical point of view there are also "higher beings" like angels. There could also be other beings we are not aware of (aliens for example).
Some argue that all creation is a spectrum/hierarchy and there are many higher beings than humans. For example Jonathan Pageau:

Pageau makes frequent reference to higher beings in his videos and
discusses them in two slightly different ways. In the first way, he
references the non-corporeal beings of Christian tradition, the
catch-all phrase for which is angels but who form a hierarchy of
different ranks including principalities, thrones, dominions, etc.11
In the second way, he speaks of principles which unify parts into
wholes. These are something like the spiritual identities of composite
earthly phenomena.

Let's look what Thomas Aquinas has to say about angels in Summa Theologica:

Next we have to investigate how angels became bad, first with respect
to the evil of sin (question 63) and second with respect to the evil
of punishment (question 64). On the first topic there are nine
questions: (1) Can the evil of sin exist in an angel?
...
(9) Did as many angels fall as remained faithful?
...
Article 1 Can the evil of sin exist in angels?
It seems that the evil of
sin (malum culpae) cannot exist in angels:
...
I respond: Angels,
along with other rational creatures, are such that if they are
considered just in their nature alone, then they are able to sin;

So angels can sin.

Article 9 Did as many angels sin as remained faithful?
It seems that
more angels sinned than remained faithful
...
I respond: The angels who
remained faithful were more numerous than those who sinned. For sin is
contrary to an angel’s natural inclination, and things that are
contrary to nature occur in fewer cases, since nature attains its
effect always or for the most part.
...

So most angels did not sin (and will never do).
Thus I would argue God created such beings,
but does not limit himself to create only such beings
